# ElasticSearch: Search across multiple fields with input strings (NumberFormatException)

Tags: elasticsearch

I am searching across multiple fields in a query using the `*` asterisk notation (Ex: I want all fields startings with `source` so I specify fields `source.*`) and I specify a query of `foobar` as string. I am using a `Query String` type query.

I keep getting a `NumberFormatException` and I have some fields in there with a mapping type of `long` and `double`.

Any idea how to go about this? I need to do a multi-field search.

My query is posted below:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [{
                "query_string": {
                    "default_field": "source.*",
                    "query": "foobar"
                }
            }],
            "must_not": [],
            "should": []
        }
    },
    "from": 0,
    "size": 100000,
    "sort": [],
    "facets": {}
}
```

Comment: And you were expecting not to get an exception when trying to compare a string to a numeric field?

Comment: Can we see the mapping?

Comment: @bittusarkar I was hoping if there was a work around. I was expecting to get the exception.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

set [lenient](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) to ***true*** to ignore format based failures

example :

```
"query_string": 
 {
      "default_field": "source.*",
      "query": "foobar",
      "lenient": true

 }
```